# How to use file from phone system in bundleResourceIO

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to bundle resources using bundleResourceIO. It works if I import a static file but I cannot make it work with dynamically fetched file from file system.

Below works;

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

import modelJson from '../assets/model.json';
import modelGroup from '../assets/group.bin'; 

...
const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(
  bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelGroup),
);
...
```

I cannot make it work if I read the file dynamically as below;

- This is how I read files;

```
const rootPath =
  Platform.OS === 'ios' ? RNFS.MainBundlePath : RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;

async function readFileFromSystem(filePath: string) {
  return await RNFS.readFile(
    `${rootPath}/${filePath}`,
    filePath.endsWith('.bin') ? 'base64' : 'utf8',
  )
    .then((result) => {
      return result;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.message, err.code);
    });
}

const modelJson = await readFileFromSystem(
  'model/model.json',
);

const modelGroup = await readFileFromSystem(
  'model/group.bin',
);
```

- Below options return `Error: modelWeightsID must be a number. Have you wrapped yor asset path in a require() statment?` as expected because modelGroup is `typeof string` I can't get it as 'number'

```
const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(
  bundleResourceIO(JSON.parse(modelJson), modelGroup),
);
```

```
const modelGroupBuffer = tf.util.encodeString(modelGroup1, 'base64').buffer;
const raw = new Uint8Array(modelGroupBuffer);

const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(
  bundleResourceIO(JSON.parse(modelJson1), raw),
);
```

I also tried these options to see what it is going to return;

`parseInt(modelGroup)` and `parseInt(modelGroupBuffer)` returns `Error: Module "NaN" is missing from the asset registry`

`parseInt(raw)` returns `Error: Module "98" is missing from the asset registry`